# What kind of cleanup occurs from the process after calling exit() in C?

Tags: c, process, kernel, resource-cleanup

If I call exit() implicitly:

```
int main(){
  return 0; /*exit(0) is being called */
}
```

or explicitly:

```
int main(){
  exit(0);
  return 0; /* this is never reached */
}
```

The end-point is the same: *exit()* is being called. Now according to some sources, *exit()* will make the process do some **cleanup** before handing control back to the OS.

I know that eventually the kernel(the OS) is going to release all the resources. So what is so special with the process cleaning up before giving control to the kernel? What is excactly this *cleanup*? Why is it neccesary? How does the process know what to *cleanup*?

Comment: What is `void main()`? That's not standard C, which makes your question a bit difficult to answer.

Comment: @CodyGray I fixed the return values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ever, this question can be solved with reference to the C specification (N1256). 7.20.4.3 Gives this definition for `exit()`:

---

**3.** First, all functions registered by the `atexit` function are called, in the reverse order of their registration except that a function is called after any previously registered functions that had already been called at the time it was registered. If, during the call to any such function, a call to the `longjmp` function is made that would terminate the call to the registered function, the behavior is undefined.

**4.** Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, and all files created by the `tmpfile` function are removed.

**5.** Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS,` an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE,` an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

---

Or in English:

First call all registered `atexit` functions. Next flush all unwritten buffered data. Next close open streams. Finally, return the exit status and control to the OS.

Comment: I guess I will stick with English. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

The C runtime library supports running user code when the process exits, set using the `atexit()` function. This is not something the underlying operating system knows about, so the code in [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html) needs to implement this, for instance.

Comment: But if atexit() is not being used, what is the *cleanup* all about?

Comment: @Pithikos: did you read through that link to the `exit` documentation? It tells you what happens (POSIX and C99 specify the same thing in this respect)

Answer (score 0):

This is OS-specific, but typically on modern platforms, open files will be closed and their in-process (`stdio`) buffers flushed. Other cleanup will be handled OS-side.

Comment: Isn't memory going to be freed by the kernel?

Comment: Last I checked, the kernel was part of the operating system.

Comment: @Pithikos: you're right, the process probably won't have anything to do with the memory freeing. Restricted the answer to open file closing.